# Quadratic formula outputting 0 and -0 regardless of the terms given

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, c++17

I am trying to make a program to find the zeros of any given trinomial, the formula seems right but I don't know why the output is always -0, 0. I thought it was a compiler or IDE error but nope, same error in both VS Code 2019 and Code Blocks. There is some weird logic error I am not seeing.

Also, I am well aware I don't have any kind of validation statement but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double a = 0.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0;

    cout << "Write your a, b, and c terms separated by one space: ";
    cin >> a, b, c;

    // Quadratic Formula -> -(b)+-((b^2)-4(a)(c)) / 2(a)
    double ans1 = 0.0, ans2 = 0.0;
    ans1 = (-b + sqrt((b*b) - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a);
    ans2 = (-b - sqrt((b*b) - 4.0 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a);

    cout << "1st Answer: " << ans1 << "\n";
    cout << "2nd Answer: " << ans2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @mkrieger1 That is actually a very helpful article. Thank you :D

Comment: You’re welcome, I’m glad you actually read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin >> a, b, c;` really doesn't do what you want.
It's pretty similar to  `cin >> a; b; c;`, which is pretty similar to `cin >> a;`.

You want `cin >> a >> b >> c`.

#### As an aside...

A reasonable compiler would also warn you about this behavior. Since it's unlikely what to be what you intended.

```
> clang++ -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:11:15: warning: expression result unused
      [-Wunused-value]
    cin >> a, b, c;
              ^
main.cpp:11:18: warning: expression result unused
      [-Wunused-value]
    cin >> a, b, c;
                 ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Omg I didn't notice that!! Thank you so much!

Comment: For fun, the [solution with complex roots](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc51e2062400ea5c): for `2x²+3x+5` returns (-0.75,1.39194 i) and (-0.75,-1.39194 i)